# Cannot view the list of GitHub Repository in Build Trigger settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

The company I belong to sets https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on .

In this case, if my set up Cloud Build Trigger with my company's G Suite Account, I can display a list of GitHub Repository.

However, even if I want to set a Trigger on a personal GitHub Repository with a gmail.com account, I will get an error trying to get all Organization Repositories.

Is there a workaround for this?

[image]

Comment: can you confirm you have the source.repos.list permission?

Comment: Yes. I am the owner of this project.

```
gcloud source repos list --project gcpug-container
REPO_NAME                              PROJECT_ID       URL
github-gcpug-docker-appengine-go       gcpug-container  ssh://git@github.com/gcpug/docker-appengine-go.git
github_gcpug_docker-firebase-tools     gcpug-container  https://github.com/gcpug/docker-firebase-tools.git
github_gcpug_ds2bq                     gcpug-container  https://github.com/gcpug/ds2bq.git
github_sinmetal_docker-firebase-tools  gcpug-container  https://github.com/sinmetal/docker-firebase-tools.git
```